# Pass a class/package/theme option to R with knitr

Tags: beamer, r, knitr, themes

I have a `beamer` document with `R` chunks, say 'template.Rnw', which I compile with `knitr` using 'compile PDF' in **RStudio**. I have defined a theme 'mytheme.sty'. I would like to have an option to the theme called `French` and call it thus at the top of the document:

```
    \usetheme[French]{mytheme}
```

This 'French' theme defines label-formatting options for graphics that differ from a US style, e.g. `$1,000,000.00` printed as `1 000 000,00$`.

I thought I could create a boolean `French == 1` inside 'mytheme.sty' and then pass it to an `R` chunk for use in a conditional, `if (French) { # set the French styles here`.

But, to begin with, I do not know how to pass a `LaTeX` counter value (say) to an `R` chunk. Also, perhaps there is a better approach. If so, I'd love to know. Below is my MWE (**Warning:** does not compile!)

**template.Rnw**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{mytheme}
%\usetheme[French]{mytheme}

<<'setup', include=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
@

% I'd want to hide this chunk inside mytheme.sty or similar
<<'formats', include=FALSE>>=
# Create euro currency symbol in plot labels with library(scales)
euro <- function(x) {
paste0("€", format(x, big.mark = ",", decimal.mark = ".", trim = TRUE,
    scientific = FALSE))
} 
# French style formatting for euro labels
euroFrench <- function(x) {
paste0(format(x, big.mark = " ", decimal.mark = ",", trim = TRUE,
    scientific = FALSE), " €")
} 
# French style formatting for dollar labels
dollarFrench <- function(x) {
paste0(format(x, big.mark = " ", decimal.mark = ",", trim = TRUE,
    scientific = FALSE), " $")
} 
#  Toggle On/Off to set formats to French or US
if (French) {  # Here reads the boolean French set by the option [French]
  euro <- euroFrench      # set the custom 'euro' style to custom 'euroFrench'
  dollar <- dollarFrench  # overwrite the default 'dollar' styles of library(scales)
}
@

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{One day I will be a dual-axis euro/dollar plot}
<<'plot', out.width='1\\linewidth'>>=
df <- data.frame(x = c(0, .0001, .0002, .0003), y = c(0, 1000000, 2000000, 3000000))
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_line() + theme_classic(30) + scale_x_continuous(labels = dollar) + scale_y_continuous(labels = euro)
@
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**mytheme.sty**

```
\newcounter{French}
\newif\if@themeFrench%
\@themeFrenchfalse%
\DeclareOption{French}{\@themeFrenchtrue}%
\ProcessOptions%
\if@themeFrench% 
\setcounter{French}{1}
@
\fi
```

**Plot**  obtained with `R` outside of the `beamer` class.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way (at least not a straightforward way) to pass LaTeX variables to R. The opposite is much easier, i.e. use R variables to write LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
<<include=FALSE>>=
French <- 1
@

<<results='asis'>>=
if (French == 1) cat('\\usepackage[French]{mytheme}')
@

\begin{document}

...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! My intent was to set up the theme such that a user familiar with ``LaTeX``, but not perhaps too familiar with ``R`` and ``knitr``, would easily switch the styles from French to US. If the user has to toggle ``French <- 1`` and ``French <- 0``, I think it is equally convenient to toggle ``euro <- euroFrench`` and ``dollar <- dollarFrench``. The 'Frenchness' or otherwise of the theme is fully located in the ``R`` code, so there is no real need to go from ``R`` to ``LaTeX``. However, it might be useful in another application to have your example.

Comment: If going from ``LaTeX`` to ``R`` is not straightforward, it may be prone to errors for someone like me, so perhaps I'd better move on from this idea. However, just in case, I'll leave the question open a little while longer. Thanks again!